# Installing a Ring Flood Light Camera

Tags: electrical, motion-sensor

I want to install a Ring Floodlight Camera, in place of a motion detector outside the garage. The Motion detector triggers the 4 lights above of the garage to turn on, and there is a switch inside the house that can turn the lights on and off. Additionally, I replaced the lights above the garage with LEDs of the same spec.

I took off the motion detector without taking not of the wiring, but inside the junction box outside of the garage, there is no "hot wire" thats easily identifiable.

Out of the junction box, there is a (1) White wire (2) gray wire (3) bare wire. 
Out of the ring floodlight camera, there is a (1) white wire (2) black wire (3) bare wire.

Does anyone know what to do in place of no easily identifiable "hot wire", coming out of the junction box?

My initial impressions are:(JB)Bare Wire to(RFL)Bare wire(then ground to junction box);(JB)Gray Wire             to(RFL)White Wire;(JB)White Wire to (RFL)Black wire.

My reasoning for the (JB)white wire to (RFL)black wire is that the two neutral colored wires coming from the junction box, seem to be indicative of a switch loop?

Also, I'm wondering if there be a problem with (1) replacing a motion sensor that triggers the lights above the garage, with a ring floodlight and (2) could the LEDs that are currently being triggered by the motion detector, cause problems with the ring floodlight camera?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you can provide a photo of your Motion-LED light setup.  I am assuming you only have one box with motion dector and Led lights mounted as a unit.  If the LED lights mounted on separate boxes, then I can provide a better answer to question 2.

Comment: Hi, the RFL is the motion detector and lights. The current motion detector is a stand-alone unit, and it triggers 3 individual lights built into the house, that go above the garage door.

Comment: @JosephDep, so if the current motion detector triggers the other lights, then it is just acting like a light switch?  Does that sound right?  In that case, you might not have any hot wires in the motion detector box, just a "switch loop".

Comment: Also, does your ring camera not have a red wire as shown in [this help page](https://support.ring.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023859972-Connecting-External-Lights-to-Your-Spotlight-Cam-Mount)?

Comment: Hi yes, exactly, the 3 additional lights are built into the home, and yes it is the same setup as displayed on the webiste.

Comment: I deleted my Ans I do not believe we know enough about the wiring plan used in the motion box.  Is it a switch loop, or a hot feet switch. If it was a switch loop, and the motion box is only acting as a switch, then the white wire should have been marked with black tape, or other markers to show it was not a neutral wire.  With white, gray, ground as the wire coming into the box, It is inferring that both wire are neutral.  If the white is being used as a hot, it should have been taped or marked with black or other color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of "garage motion light" that most people are familiar with has a motion detector and two floodlights built into one package.  This is what the Ring is trying to duplicate.  However, there is a more... architectural option.  You put only the motion detection pod where its needed, and it controls other lights that are mounted separately.

I believe this second case is what we are talking about, and in this method, the motion switch just acts like a light switch and doesn't have power going to it.  If there are only two wires in the motion detector box, then this is acting like a switch loop and you can't install a Ring light there as it sits.

If conduit is running to the box, you may be able to pull an additional wire, but there is another option.  If you don't want to switch the existing lights any more (they would be dead) and instead want only the ring light to work, you can turn the switch loop into a normal hot and neutral wire.

To do that, you would want to open up the boxes for the switched lights on the garage and see where the white and grey wire to the motion detector end up.  Once you find the other end of the white and grey, you can then rewire them to provide power to the Ring.  If you need more help with that, it would be a new question with pictures, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Hi JPhi, thank you, that answers everything. With that being said, I now need to put the motion detector back into box, and as i said i did not pay particular attention to the wiring. If the junction box has the (a)white, (b)gray, and (c)bare wire, and the motion sensor has the (a)green, (b)black, (c)red, and (d)white wire, would the proper connections be (1) JB bare to green (2) JB white to white and (3) JB gray to black/red?

Comment: @JosephDep, I didn't really expect your motion detector pod to have a white wire since you only have two wires and a ground in that box.  Are you sure that the white black and red wires from the motion detector were all hooked up?

Comment: To be honest, no i am not sure if they were all hooked up, but yes the motion detector pod does have a white wire

Comment: it would help if we knew the brand/model of the motion detector to determine its wiring requirements and how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: It is an ultitech Motion Activated Replacement sensor. model number GYQ27-W

Comment: @JosephDep Unfortunately I can't find the instructions for that, but _in general_, the white wire is neutral, the black wire is hot, and the red wire is the switched output that would power the lights attached to the house.  The motion detector powers itself from the white and black wires.  That's the way its done when you have three wires in the box...  If this was working before it was wired incorrectly but luckily working (maybe not totally safe) or there's a special way to wire the detector without a neutral.

Comment: It appears that this motion detector was part of a complete unit.  Does the Unit have a red wire, and if yes, what is it connected to?

Comment: Is there also a light switch that turns this circuit on and off?

Comment: There is a light switch that turns the circuit on and off. As far as being part of a unit, I am not quite sure. I know it was replaced maybe a year or two ago, not by me and replaced the original sensor that was there from when the house was built in 92. Only reason for opening it up, was to install the ring ha, which I now know I can't (within my ability) do.

Comment: @JosephDep, looks like Lowes still sells that model.  You could take a pic of the instructions and see if it has an option for no-neutral install.  If the last person was naughty they could have used the bare ground as a neutral, but you really shouldn't do that.

Comment: Jphi, Sounds good. I should have paid more attention taking the sensor off. Assuming it is a switch loop, which is what it seems from what I've read and what you had said, with a white, gray, and bare wire; and the Ultitech sensor has a red, white, black, and ground wire, what would "technically" be the ideal wiring arrangement?

Comment: I have seen in-wall motion detectors that do not need a neutral so they would be installed (with your colors) black wire to grey and red wire to white (or vice versa).  In this arrangement they can parasitically draw a small voltage from the circuit as long as compatible bulbs are installed in the socket.  Green would go to the bare ground.  Green is always just a safety ground and doesn't carry current.  But, there is a chance you could damage the motion detector or something else by just trying things...

Comment: JPhi, figured i would update this. I tried your method and nothing happened. Assuming ground is left as if, if I connect black and red to white, and white to gray, the motion sensor pod blinks, so it is getting power, but the lights are not turning on. Tried the breaker trick, and trying the switch, no light. Im throwing in the towel and calling an electrician.